# Retrieve Location metadata using latitude and longitude coordinates using google Maps API's

Tags: google-maps, machine-learning, feature-selection

I am working on a machine learning problem. As part of the given data, one of the given data is latitude and longitude coordinates. 
I was looking for a way to manipulate this location data, so that I can improve my prediction percentage.

So as part of that I was checking if there exists any google maps api which can take as input this latitude and longtitude data, and return the metadata about that location. The metadata returned can then help me in grouping this data into certain section. The kind of metadata that I am looking for is something like this:

1. Address
2. Address type(whether commercial or residential)
3. population of that region
4. etc..

Is there any API available in google which can be used for this purpose? Any other article related to manipulating location coordinates also would be helpful.

Comment: Look at the Geocoding and Places APIs (verify that you can legally use them for your purpose before using them).

Answer (score 0):

Check

https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/51.500/-0.100

It is likely to prove useful !